# func.count(distinct(...)) does not give the same result as distinct().count()

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a column with null entries, e.g. the possible values in this column are `None, 1, 2, 3`

When I count the number of unique entries in the column with `session.query(func.count(distinct(Entry.col))).scalar()` I get back '3'.

But when I perform the count with `session.query(Entry.col).distinct().count()`, I get back '4'.

Why does the latter method count the `None`, but the first doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, the resulting query will look like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(col)) FROM Entry
```

... and, as you probably already know, `COUNT` here won't actually count the `NULL` values.

In the second case, however, the query is different, as shown in [**the doc**](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/query.html?highlight=count#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.count):

```
SELECT count(1) AS count_1 FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT(col) FROM Entry
) AS anon_1
```

Now that just counts the total number of the rows returned by `SELECT DISTINCT` query (which is 4 - NULL *is* included in the output of DISTINCT queries).

The reason is simple: `query.count` purpose is to return the number of rows the query would have returned if run without `count` clause. This method doesn't give you control over which columns should be used to count - that's what `func.count(...)` is for.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL COUNT doesn't count NULL values, so if you are counting values by a field that has NULL values, that rows won't be counted by COUNT.

DISTINCT returns just number of *different* values so NULL is included.